# Forecast Model recognize future trend

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, predictive-models, feature-selection, random-forest

I set up a forecasting model that predicts call data. The forecast model uses a random forest regression model.

Data:
I have call data about every day in 15 minutes intervals of a year since 2013.

Here is a plot of the accumulated values over months:

[image: Calldata]

It can be clearly seen that call data has almost doubled in 2017 over 2016. This trend should also be observable for the next few years.

features:

First, the format of my data:

```
 DATE                     CALL
 ....
 2017-10-23 10:15:00.000    259
 2017-10-23 10:30:00.000    292
 2017-10-23 10:45:00.000    309
 ....
```

From this I extracted the following features:
I have extracted the following features to predict my target variable Y (call data):

```
-Weekday
-Month
-Holiday (yes / no)
-Interval of the day

So I ask my model:

What is the call volume of a day and interval with the following features?
```

I have used the years 2015-2016-2017 to train the model. However, the model does not give the desired prognosis.

He even predicts the days for 2017 wrong. Although I gave him the data as training data.

Questions:

```
- Should I work on my features?

- How do I show my forecasting model that the data will double year by year 
  as observable since 2016?
```

Comment: One of the characteristics (I like to think of it as an advantage) is that a random forest model won't predict outside the range of the observed data. This is easier to see if you run a single decision tree instead of a forest of them. There is no terminal node in your decision tree that will predict 400,000, but that's what you seem to expect to occur in the near future.

Comment: (part 2) Now, there might be some way to transform the data (e.g. to predict percent change versus year ago rather than just call volume), but I'm not sure random forest (or decision trees, for that matter) is really what you want in predicting something that's growing fast.

Comment: what kind of model would you suggest? @zbicyclist

Comment: You need to reflect autocorrelation, and you have "causal" factors. I'd try a dynamic regression model.  This is described in section 9.1 of Hyndman and Athana­sopou­los:  https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1